# 私はこの力を以て己れを鞭ち他を生きる事が出来るように思う

Tags: meaning, literature

There's a sentence in the "to the little ones " story I can't understand, I searched a lot, and I don't get the writer's meaning.

> 私はこの力を以て己れを鞭ち他を生きる事が出来るように思う。([source: 『小さき者へ』](http://www.suguru.jp/learn/chiisaki.htm))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 私はこの力を[以]{もっ}て[己]{おの}れを[鞭]{むちう}ち他を生きる事が出来るように思う。

I think it means

> 私は、この力を使って自分を奮い立たせ、他の生き方ができると思う。
> I feel that I will be able to push myself hard with this ability/strength (to do the three things mentioned right before) and live in a different way (from the way I lived before your mother died).

To break it down:

私は I
この力を以て using this ability/strength; with this ability/strength
己れを鞭ち push myself hard; drive myself hard
他を生きる live differently; live in a different way
事が出来る can; will be able to
ように思う feel like, think

Answer (score 1):

Modern translation(I changed a little)

> 私はこの経験から得た力から,自分を鍛え、他の場所でも生きていけるようになると思う。

English:

> I think I will be able to use the power I gained from this experience to train myself and exist elsewhere.

It may not be accurate, sorry.